# Three JS object added geometries broken

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js

So I have a model, `playerModel`, and I have another mesh where I need to orient a line to.

When I add the line as a children of the scene,everything works as expected, but if I add the line to the player model, the line is going to a totally wrong direction.

```
 var laserGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
 var line = new THREE.Line(laserGeometry, laserMaterial);

 laserGeometry.vertices = [];
 laserGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
 laserGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(23,38,80));

 scene.add(skyDome);
 scene.add(playerModel);
 playerModel.add(camera);
 playerModel.add(line);
```

By default the player model is oriented facing Z, but I don't see this as being an issue.
I have checked if there is any error in the coordinates system, but there isn't... not sure though if the coordinates I'm linking the end of the line towards a local variable in the `playerModel`, if that's true.. Is there any way in having the second vector coordinates relative to scene?